# How to use spring data repository for mongodb to fetch data from mongo repositories with dynamic field names?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data JPA to fetch data from mongoDB.

```
public interface SupplierResponseRepo extends MongoRepository<SupplierResponse, String>  {}

@Document
public class SupplierResponse{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String supplierResponseId;
    private String orderId;
    private String orderName;
}
```

Above code used to work until all fields name were fixed, now there can be multiple fields and their names are not known in advance, and I want all fields to be fetched.
Is there any way I can do the same , like I can pass any generic type to MongoRepository interface and fetch all columns.

I had same problem with mongoTemplate but then it was resolved using DBObject.

```
mongoTemplate.find(query, DBObject.class,"supplier");
```

Is there similar alternative for MongoRepository  as well?

Comment: To be sure I understood well, the names that are not known in advance are the name of the attributes the `SupplierResponse` class?

Comment: @charlycou SupplierResponse class has fixed variable names lets say suppliername, but SupplierResponse collection in mongo can have different name like supp_name, so how do I map them. lets say I have mapping of suppliername=supp_name, but how do I fetch all fields from collection using MongoRepository, as it need to have same variable names as fields present in collection

Comment: I suggest you to use custom converter. I'll answer your question with that suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use custom Converter class to fetch your data using MongoRepository. Since it's data from Mongodb you need to map in your Spring Data application, it's a `@ReadingConverter` that you need.

```
/**
 * @ReadingConverter: Spring data mongodb annotation to enable the class to handle the mapping of DBObject into Java
 * Objects
 */
@ReadingConverter
public class SupplierResponseConverter implements Converter<Document, SupplierResponse> {
    /**
     * Map DBObject to SupplierResponse inherited class according to the MongoDB document attributes
     * @param source MongoDB Document object
     * @return SupplierResponse Object
     */
    @Override
    public SupplierResponse convert(Document source) {
        if (source.get("supp_id") != null) {
            SupplierResponse supplierResponse = new SupplierResponse();
            supplierResponse.setSupplierId(source.get("supp_id", String.class)
        }
        //repeat this operation for all your attribute in order to map them according to a condition of your choice
}
```

Then, you need to enable your custom converter class in a `@Configuration` class. You can do it this way. By extending `AbstractMongoConfiguration` you will have to override few other methods.

```
/**
 * @Configuration: allow to register extra Spring beans in the context or import additional configuration classes
 */
@Configuration
public class DataportalApplicationConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    //@Value: inject property values into components
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String uri;
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;

    /**
     * Configure the MongoClient with the uri
     *
     * @return MongoClient.class
     */
    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(uri));
    }

    /**
     * Database name getter
     *
     * @return the database the query will be performed
     */
    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return database;
    }

    /**
     * @Bean: explicitly declare that a method produces a Spring bean to be managed by the Spring container.
     * Configuration of the custom converter defined for the entity schema.
     * @return MongoCustomConversions.class
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converterList = new ArrayList<>();
        converterList.add(new ContactReadConverter());
        converterList.add(new GeometryGeoJSONReadConverter());
        converterList.add(new SamplingFeatureReadConverter());
        converterList.add(new SensorReadConverter());
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converterList);
    }

    /**
     * @Bean: explicitly declare that a method produces a Spring bean to be managed by the Spring container.
     * Configuration of the MongoTemplate with the newly defined custom converters. The MongoTemplate class is the
     * central class of Spring’s MongoDB support and provides a rich feature set for interacting with the database. The
     * template offers convenience operations to create, update, delete, and query MongoDB documents and provides a
     * mapping between your domain objects and MongoDB documents.
     *
     * @return MongoTemplate.class
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
        MappingMongoConverter mongoMapping = (MappingMongoConverter) mongoTemplate.getConverter();
        mongoTemplate.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION);
        mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY);
        mongoMapping.setCustomConversions(customConversions()); // tell mongodb to use the custom converters
        mongoMapping.afterPropertiesSet();
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I  add configuration class I get below error

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/MyApplicationConfig .class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MongoClient must not be null!

Comment: because below are default methods of AbstractMongoConfiguration  

public MongoClient mongoClient() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return null;
}

protected String getDatabaseName() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return null;
}

Comment: You can give it a try without extending `AbstractMongoConfiguration`. I don't know if this bean will override default behaviour. Otherwise, you can override `AbstractMongoConfiguration` - see edit